# Passing slot into slot in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, core-ui

I'm trying to pass slot into the slot but child component which requires passed down slot doesn't see it.

In the child (TheTable) I have table component from Core UI for Vue (CDataTable) which requires certain slots which I want to pass from a parent:

```
  <CDataTable
      class="overflow-auto"
      :items="this.items"
      :fields="fieldData"
      :sorter="{ external: true, resetable: true }"
      :sorter-value="this.sorterValue"
      :table-filter="{ external: true, lazy: false, placeholder: 'Enter here', label: 'Search:'}"
      :responsive="false"
      :loading="this.loading"
      :hover="true"
      :items-per-page-select="true"
      :items-per-page="this.perPage"
      @pagination-change="paginationChanged"
      @update:sorter-value="sorterUpdated"
      @update:table-filter-value="filterUpdated"
  >
      <slot name="requiredTableFields"></slot>
  </CDataTable>
```

In the parent component I have:

```
<TheTable
        v-bind:fields="fields"
        v-bind:endpoint-url="endpointUrl"
>
    <template slot="requiredTableFields">
        <td slot="name" slot-scope="{item}">
            <div>{{ item['attributes.email'] }}</div>
            <div class="small text-muted">
                {{ item['attributes.firstname'] }} {{ item['attributes.lastname'] }}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td slot="registered" slot-scope="{item}">
            <template v-if="item['attributes.created_at']">{{ item['attributes.created_at'] }}</template>
            <template v-else>Not setup yet</template>
        </td>
    </template>
</TheTable>
```

Is there any way to make it work?
Cheers, 
Casper

Comment: with vue 2.6 there is a new [way](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) `template v-slot:requiredTableFields`

Comment: Sadly no luck, problem appears to be in that the table doesnt see its slots...

Comment: CDataTable expects templates for it's slots. you need to set expected templates first. i think you are trying to pass this templates from a parent component is that correct ?.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to pass them from the parent. Actually can't set up those templates there because they will vary, component with CDataTable is going to be used for abstraction.

Comment: I don't thing it is possible but you could try using the following library
https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merging the underlying slots into a single `requiredTableFields` slot isn't going to work because there's no (easy) way to break the child slots back out once they've been merged.

Instead you can just keep the slots separate:

```html
<TheTable ...>
  <template v-slot:name="{ item }">
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </template >
  <template v-slot:registered="{ item }">
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </template>
</TheTable>
```

This is passing two scoped slots, `name` and `registered`, into `TheTable`.

Assuming you don't want to hard-code the slot names into `TheTable` you'd then need to iterate over the `$scopedSlots` to include them dynamically.

```html
<CDataTable ...>
  <template v-for="(x, slotName) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slotName]="context">
    <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="context" />
  </template>
</CDataTable>
```

Some notes on this:

1. `x` is not used, we just need to loop over the slot names.
2. The 'data' associated with the scoped slot is referred to as `context` and is just passed on.
3. If the slots weren't scoped slots it'd be slightly different. We'd iterate over `$slots` instead and remove all the parts that refer to `context`.
4. There is a `:` at the start of the `:name` attribute as we want to pass a dynamic name. It is an unfortunate coincidence that one of the slots in the original question is also called `name`, potentially leading to some confusion here.
5. The `v-bind="context"` part is analogous to the JavaScript spread operator, if that makes it any clearer. Think of it as `attributes = { name: slotName, ...context }`.

Below is a complete example illustrating this technique outlined above. It doesn't use `CDataTable` but the core principle for passing on the slots is exactly the same.

```js
const Comp2 = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4>Left</h4>
      <div><slot name="top" item="Red" /></div>
      <h4>Right</h4>
      <div><slot name="bottom" item="Green" /></div>
    </div>
  `
}

const Comp1 = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <comp2>
        <template v-for="(x, slotName) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slotName]="context">
          <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="context" />
        </template>
      </comp2>
    </div>
  `,
  
  components: {
    Comp2
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    Comp1
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <comp1>
    <template v-slot:top="{ item }">
      <button>Slot 1 - {{ item }}</button>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:bottom="{ item }">
      <button>Slot 2 - {{ item }}</button>
    </template>
  </comp1>
</div>
```